# Nginx Troubleshooting; not redirecting correctly

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I am currently trying to deploy my Django app on an Ubuntu 18.04.3 droplet. I am following along with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I have successfully completed the tutorial, and my app is served when visiting my server's IP and "www.domainname.com". However, when I try to visit my domain's address without the "www" @ 'domainname.com' it shows

> refused to connect.

And as I stated before, when I go to directly to the IP address it displays 100% correctly and serves the app's static files.

I'm assuming it has something to do with NGINX configuration because I completed every other part of the tutorial correctly with no errors.

Here is my NGINX server block @ `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 165.227.222.0;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ethan/cfsite/cfsite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I commented out the default server block completely in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` as I read it is symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

When I `sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log` I get this:

```
2019/09/26 14:25:58 [alert] 6680#6680: *3 open socket #3 left in connection 4
2019/09/26 14:25:58 [alert] 6680#6680: aborting
```

I am assuming there is some issue with a proxy somewhere or the registrar is not correctly redirecting to DigitalOcean being that accessing the DO IP directly yields the correct results with static files served.

Please help! It's a simple portfolio website, and I've never configured a server before.

Comment: Is there any configuration where your server_name is www.domainname.com and not your ip? you should also put www.domainname.com and domainname.com in server_name. If you do "dig domainname.com" in your terminal what ip does it return, is it yours?

Comment: @flaixman when I dig my domainname, for some reason it lists the droplet I used before I created the current one. I deleted the prior one to start fresh with the process, and there is no reference to it in any records or config files in the new droplet?

Comment: Have you changed where the DNS is pointing?

Comment: @flaixman Yes. I just transferred the domain to namecheap because I thought it may have been an issue with the registrars DNS services. So, now on Namecheap I have my domain point to "ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com". I then have my DO project with 5 dns records: the 3 pointing my domain to DO's nameservers, and 2 A records pointing "www." and "@" to my IP address. Now it's only displaying my website on the server IP and not on "domainname.com" or "www.domainname.com".

Comment: add on server_name your domains: server_name 165.227.222.0 www.domainname.com domainname.com ; and it should work.

Comment: I tried that and routing to “domainname.com” is still displaying “refused to connect to server”. I double checked my django settings as well, and both are inside of “accepted-ip”. So it is now in the nginx proxy and my django accepted ip. Im not really sure where else to look for solutions at this point.